# strtolwer strange behaviour in different environments with multibyte characters

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

There are 5 machines.

Mine is a win10 64bit, php 5.6, production server is latest debian 64bit with php 5.6.

Both of two machines run the same script with the same results. The strange is the difference between run the script from web, and from command line.

The code:

```
$string = chr(194) . chr(160);
var_dump($string);
var_dump(bin2hex($string));
var_dump(bin2hex(strtolower($string)));
var_dump(bin2hex(mb_strtolower($string)));
```

The output from web:

```
string(2) " "
string(4) "c2a0"
string(4) "c2a0"
string(4) "c2a0"
```

Strange is, that both machine is do the same in command line:

```
string(2) " "
string(4) "c2a0"
string(4) "e2a0"  <-- Listen this!
string(4) "c2a0"
```

for some reason, strtolower has changed the first byte of the UTF8 char.

My colleaguge has a raspberry 32 bit, with PHP7, another server with 64bit CentOs with PHP7, and there is one more machine CentOs 64bit PHP 5.3.3.

But these machines dumps everywhere the `c2a0`. Of course, we use UTF8 charset everywhere for everything.

What can cause this?

**EDIT:**

On production: `setlocale(LC_ALL,0);`

Command line:

```
 LC_CTYPE=en_US;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

From web:

```
string(1) "C"
```

On my localhost machine:

From web:

```
string(1) "C"
```

Command line:

```
  LC_COLLATE=C;LC_CTYPE=Hungarian_Hungary.1250;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C
```

Comment: check if both command line and web is using the same php.ini. try `phpinfo();` for web and `php --ini` in command line

Comment: My machine is using the same, `C:\PHP\php.ini`.  On prod server the `phpinfo()` has disabled, but I will ask.

Comment: if `phpinfo()` is disabled check if [php_ini_loaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php) works

Comment: @bansi On prod is not the same, but as I mentioned, on localhost is the same.

Comment: Try to run `echo setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);` in both environments and compare results.

Comment: try `echo ini_get('default_charset');` and see if it is really using `UTF8`. alternatively you can try `ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`setlocale`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) function before using string functions on multibyte strings.

Comment: How is this related to my question? First of all, `chr(194) . chr(160);` is just a `SHIFT+SPACE`, is the shift space is something else in german and english?

Comment: Using setlocale you may set **encoding** in current process.

Comment: @vaso123, `chr(194)` is from extended ASCII table and differs from locale to locale. The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) reads: *Note that 'alphabetic' is determined by the current locale. This means that e.g. in the default "C" locale, characters such as umlaut-A (Ä) will not be converted.*

Comment: I was judged too fast, unfortunatly can not remove downvote. Please accept my apologize for it. If I am useing `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'C')`, same in browser and command line.

Comment: Don't worry. Glad to know that you solve the problem.

Comment: @vaso123, it seems that you can undo downvote upvote my answer. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285357/2227895

Comment: @GermanLashevich Get this: You last voted on this answer 19 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited...